# Juntar 3 formulários em 1 submit

Tags: php, html, front-end

Tenho **3** formulários **:** **form1**, **form2** e **form3**.

Não sei como posso **" juntá-los "** de forma que precise apenas de um `<input type=submit />` para os **três** ao invés de criar um `Submit` para cada um

- Há alguma maneira de fazer isto?
- Se **sim**, onde posso encontrar **documentações**?

Comment: São vários forms que vão enviar os dados para o mesmo lugar?

Comment: Você só pode dar UM submit, se o que você quer é enviar os dados desses 3 forms no mesmo submit, então você precisa formular melhor sua pergunta, a começar postando os 3 forms aqui para que seja possível formular a resposta ideal.

Comment: Definitivamente você não precisa montar três formulários separados, se utilizar um pouco de Javascript basta recuperar os campos e pegar os respectivos valores deles, depois é só enviar via javascript para o servidor. Forneça um pouco do seu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que você quer enviar todos os dados no mesmo submit e que utiliza `jQuery`, vou propor a seguinte solução:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-1">
    //seus campos aqui
</form>
<form id="form-2">
    //seus campos aqui
</form>
<form id="form-3">
    //seus campos aqui
</form>
<input type="submit" id="submit-forms"/>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#submit-forms').click(function(){
        window.location.href = "urldesubmit.com.br?" + $('#form-1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form-2').serialize() + '&' + $('#form-3').serialize();
    });
});
<script>
```

É uma baita de uma gambiarra, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Aqui não funcionou teu código

Comment: Disparou algum erro? Tem algum detalhe a mais?

Comment: Poste na pergunta como você fez...

Comment: Simplesmente o submit não funcionou ficou apenas um botão sem enviar...

Comment: Tentou colocar um alert no evento pra ver se está entrando nele?

Comment: Não vai tambem! :/

Comment: consegue postar seu código na pergunta, com os forms e o jQuery?

Comment: Apenas tentei executar este código teu e não foi...

Comment: Você adicionou o jQuery na página que fez o teste? para ver os erros você tem que abrir o console do browser...se você não postar o código ou informar qual erro está ocorrendo eu não tenho como apontar a solução, fora isso os forms tem que ter os seus campos para enviar todos os dados corretamente

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** -> Código idêntico da sua respostas apenas com 1 campo `<input type="text" name="teste" />`

Comment: Você tem que adicionar o jQuery na página, editei a resposta

Comment: **perfeito* Funcionou, obrigado :D